# Are finitely generated modules over a commutative ring always a direct sum of cyclic submodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Let's first motivate my question by looking at a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$ over a field $k$.

Then $A$ in general does not have the form $k[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$ where $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ is a generating set for $A$. For example consider the two-dimensional irreducible representation $V$ of the quarternion group $Q_8$, then the ring of invariants is finitely generated by Hilbert's finiteness theorem, but  the algebra of invariants, which is a subalgebra of a polynomial algebra in two variables holds the form $$ \mathbb{C}[V]^{Q_8} = \dfrac{\mathbb{C}[f,g,h]}{(h^2-f^2g+4g^3)},$$ where $f$ and $g$ are invariant polynomials of degree 4, and $h$ is of degree 6. The reason is that the generating polynomials are not algebraically independent.

Now consider a commutative ring $R$, and $M$ a finitely generating $R$-module, and $\{m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n\}$ a generating set for $M$, I want to know whether it is true that $M$ holds the form $$ M = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n Rm_i$$

I think this is not true, but this is true if and only if $M$ is a finitely generated $\textit{free}$ module over $R$.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, it is not generally true. Rings for which finitely generated modules (and also simply just all modules) are direct sums of cyclic modules have pretty good coverage in literature.

Start with

> Behboodi, M., and G. Behboodi Eskandari. "On rings over which every finitely generated module is a direct sum of cyclic modules." Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics 45.5 (2016): 1335-1342.

and follow the citations.

> I think this is not true, but this is true if and only if  is a finitely generated free module over .

Being free is sufficient for being that form, but it will not usually be necessary. For example, if the commutative ring has a nontrivial ideal, $R/I$ is clearly cyclic, and is certainly non-free (it has nonzero annihilator.) (*Simplified thanks to metalspringpro*)

Comment: Incidentally, what a great example of titling an article well!  Makes it easy to find the answer to this problem right away, anyhow!

Comment: Just to add, as long as $R$ has a proper ideal $I$, then $R/I$ is cyclic but not free. So there are always nonfree modules having that form unless $R$ is a field.

Comment: @metalspringpro Good observation: originally I had been thinking about projectve  modules that aren't free. But in hindsight that doesn't even matter. I hope you don't mind if I simplify that using your explanation.

Comment: Sure, please do.